# How I can change google map format to jpeg?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I change google map images format here on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRqUo.png)?
I see that we have map parameters on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro. And one of them is

> **format** (optional) defines the format of the resulting image. By default, the Google Static Maps API creates PNG images. There are several possible formats including GIF, JPEG and PNG types. Which format you use depends on how you intend to present the image. JPEG typically provides greater compression, while GIF and PNG provide greater detail.

But if I use it nothing has changed. here is my code example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map;
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8,
              format: 'jpg'
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7w3f9b55/33/
(base code from google examples).

Comment: I tried this too and it's not working

Comment: ok,Ii've already updated  the question

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link to is for static maps which is when you want to embed a single static image into your web page.

The google maps javascript api doesn't allow you to control the image type, why would you want to?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It's my current task on the project and I've never did this before, but i hoped use format option. 

So no way to change the format?